# FLASH AS3 Transition manager errors

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've been away from Flash as3 for a while, but today I need to write a map link application using it and i'm pulling my hair out with an annoying problem!

I just want an overlay to appear when a map movieclip is clicked and fade out when somebody then clicks the map.  The fade in works fine, but the fade out doesn't do anything!?

Code below -

```
import fl.transitions.*;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;


var newOL:overlib = new overlib();
var TMOverlib:TransitionManager = new TransitionManager(newOL);

map_group.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showOverlib);

function showOverlib(evt:MouseEvent){

this.addChild(newOL);
newOL.x = -9;
newOL.y = -10.5;
newOL.alpha =0;
showit();
}


function showit(){

TMOverlib.startTransition({type:Fade, duration:1, direction:Transition.IN})
trace("yep");
}


newOL.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hideMe);
function hideMe(evt:MouseEvent) {
trace("got here");

TMOverlib.startTransition({type:Blinds, direction:Transition.IN, duration:2,                                easing:Strong.easeOut})


 }
```

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Cheers
Paul

Comment: note: the last transition was a fade rather than blinds, I just put the blinds in to see if that worked!  Neither do though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a Tweening library like [Tweener](http://code.google.com/p/tweener/) and then do something like...

```
Tweener.addTween(newOL,{alpha:1,time:1});
```

to show it and the opposite to hide it.